# Some ips can establish tcp connections to a server with DROP iptables rules

Tags: tcp, firewall, iptables

I have been hired to fix hacking issue for a server, I found that ip 37.187.253.240 and some other ips can connect to specific port, while they are not allowed !.

csf firewall is installed in the server, and that port is not open for all in csf.conf.

only some ips are added in list csf.allow .

current iptables status by `iptables -L` is : 
INPUT Chain (DROP policy), with ACCEPT only for some ips. and this ip 37.187.253.240 hasn't any rule.

to make sure that the csf isn't the cause if I stop csf by `csf -x` and flush the iptables rules by `iptables -F` , then added only a DROP rule `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 37.187.253.240 -j DROP` for that ip , I see it can connect also via netstat

```
tcp        0     0 server_ip:port    37.187.253.240:16132    ESTABLISHED
```

Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
, hosted in vmware.com.

what are the probabilities of this case ?

Answer (score 0):

Just to make a test, with your CSF firewall disabled and with the iptables rules flushed try this:

```
ip route add blackhole 37.187.253.240
```

This will discard all packets received from 37.187.253.240 or sent from your server to 37.187.253.240.

Then check with **netstat** and see if you still see any connection to or from ip address.

Since the server was hacked it might be possible that there is a process running on the server that previously established a connection to that ip address somehow and that connection remained active.

You could do a `lsof -i | grep 16132` and see exactly which process is using that port. If a website from that server was hacked you could restart the **httpd/apache** service just to kill the connection.